# how to get get price value from lightweight-charts?

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

I want to get the value of the point where I click on the chart.

```
    function handleClick(param) {
       document.getElementById('y_value').value = param.point.y;
    }
```

But this returns the on-screen y-axis coordinates, not the price values.

and this.

```
    function handleClick(param) {
      document.getElementById('y_value').value = param.point.param.seriesPrices.get(Series).high;
    }
```

It returns the price value, but only the value above the chart line, not the value of the point I clicked on. How do I get the price-y value even if I click on the blank space on the chart?

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miIvS.png)

I want to get that red circle value...

Comment: Did u tried using the inspector to find that id of the actual price?

Comment: @ CrynetOmega thanks, Thank you. By using inspector, I found it and solved it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Series2.coordinateToPrice(param.point.y);
```

this solved.